# install programs whitout internet access on Machine A connected to Machine B with internet access

Tags: ssh, proxy, internet, vpn

I have a Machine A with no access to internet.
I have a Machine B with access to internet.

A & B can connect to each other via ssh.

I'd like to make some program installs on A (perl, R package etc...) from internet repository using the internet connexion of B.

Is this possible & and how i could do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS'es are we talking about?

Comment: Does both machine has wi-fi?